# simple java datestamp question

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I am looking to capture the current date for a date of transaction variable.

this is the format I'm looking for.

I know simpleDateFormat works well with my db too.

here's what I've used to input the date before when it was a date that I typed in the gui:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
        try {
            ev.setDate(sdf.parse("12-10-2011"));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

**I just want to be able to get the current date instead of having to hard code a string like the above code.**

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
MM-dd-yyyy
```

**Edit**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

- [Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: just create `new Date();` to get current date time

Comment: ok great. now how do i change the format from `Wed Mar 09 23:30:47 MST 2011` to `mm-dd-yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

Plz use the below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormet("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Below is a list of possible values while initializing the `sdf` object taken from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation        Examples
G       Era designator          Text                AD
y       Year                    Year                1996; 96
M       Month in year           Month               July; Jul; 07
w       Week in year            Number              27
W       Week in month           Number              2
D       Day in year             Number              189
d       Day in month            Number              10
F       Day of week in month    Number              2
E       Day in week             Text                Tuesday; Tue
a       Am/pm marker            Text                PM
H       Hour in day (0-23)      Number              0
k       Hour in day (1-24)      Number              24
K       Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number              0
h       Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number              12
m       Minute in hour          Number              30
s       Second in minute        Number              55
S       Millisecond             Number              978
z       Time zone               General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z       Time zone               RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```